# How to calculate growth rate in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data in which "publication" readers to the number of articles published by researchers.

```
country      year  publication
South Kora   2002    23456
South Kora   2003    24456
South Kora   2004    24256
South Kora   2005    29456
South Kora   2006    23488
Pakistan     2002    4333
Pakistan     2003    4125
Pakistan     2004    3567
Pakistan     2005    5432
Pakistan     2006    2345
Armenia      2002    567
Armenia      2003    678
Armenia      2004    765
Armenia      2005    987
Armenia      2006    713
```

Now I want to calculate the growth rate of published articles for each year per country in a new column. This means I need to use this formula: publications in current year - publications in previous years) / publications in previous year and then multiplied by 100.

Comment: what have you tried so far? check out `diff(publication)/publication[-n]` (where `n` is the length of the vector) to start ... (did you do a web search? https://community.rstudio.com/t/growth-rate-calculation-in-r/38675

Comment: You can try this 
   df %>%
mutate(Growth = (publication- lag(publication))/lag(publication))